# Do we want a blog?

Tags: discussion

Many Stack Exchange communities maintain [site-specific blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs) like

- [Sci-Fi](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/)
- [Information Security](http://security.blogoverflow.com/)
- [DIY](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/)

These are intended for topics that are part of the domain but don't fit well in a Q&A format. I think there are many interesting topics we could cover in a blog if we have enough members interested in contributing posts.

This provides some guidelines regarding [community blogs](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/). So, would you like to see an Arduino.SE blog?

Would you be interested in contributing to the blog? (if yes, comment on this post)

Answer (score 3):

## No. Definitely later, but it's too early.

> We will need at least 4-5 regular writers (who can function as reviewers), and keep the blog going at minimum 1 post/2 weeks. Plus, of course, anyone would be welcome to join in to submit ideas, posts, tools, projects, etc, that we may cover, or even submit full fledged articles that could be published as-is. All of this depends on whether there are enough users interested in contributing, in the first place :) *–  AsheeshR 9 hours ago*

One post every 8/10 weeks if we have 4/5 people isn't so bad. With us three moderators, and maybe another user it's doable. I'd even be open to organizing and proofreading all of the content and uploading it as long as I have the content two days in advance. **However, will people really read it?** The Facebook page has only 7 likes. I know not everybody likes liking everything they see, however, **it does seem like we won't get many readers per post.**

I'd estimate we might get 50 a month if we're lucky at this stage. I'd say that that seems too low. The point of the blog is to expand the community's scope beyond the actual site and generate regulars, but we still need to get a little more users to make something like this worthwhile. **In the meantime, share links to our site, friends us on Facebook, or even tweet one of our questions. Try the approach that if someone asks an Arduino question online to ask it here and give them a link when it gets lots of high quality answers.** They might join us and then promote us.

I may be total wrong, but not many of the smaller betas have blogs. We're the third smallest community on the site, and I think we need to grow a little more to add something like this to make this effort successful.

Comment: I get 100-200 pageviews per month on my blog and I post less than once a month plus I dont publicise it; so your 50 views estimate seems rather pessimistic. Plus, a fair part of what we are doing is an investment a few months down the line rather than for now. Any useful content out there, irrespective of numbers, is good for us and the community. While I agree views are important, that should not be the sole driving factor here. The sharing aspect that you point out, goes without saying.

Comment: We should be sharing irrespective of the blog or other initiatives. Also, [islam.se] got its blog roughly 6-7 months after launch. I agree that this is fairly early, and I had voiced the same opinion earlier. However, we are a rather active and enthusiastic community and I think that a blog *may just* work out.

Comment: @Asheesh True, it might work out with us being active. For the Islam thing, we're a *month and a half* not 6 months. I say wait a few weeks before starting something and try to get a little more users.* For views... I guess we should keep the focus more on Arduino than on the site to gain viewers. | *It seems like we shouldn't start out with a post tomorrow, but we can start now and figure out a system.

Answer (score 2):

I think a blog could add some value to the site.

One thing off the top of my head is a question like this: ['Basic electronics' resources [on hold]](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/955/basic-electronics-resources) as a blog post than Q&A.

Comment: Could also be a place to present projects/libraries (something like the contest showcase but maybe more detailed)?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a good idea. But how will it work? (Specially in terms of when this community grows) Maybe a system of posts proposals and a group of reviewers or something like that? Or are you thinking more about having a reduced set of commiteds writers?

Comment: We will need at least 4-5 regular writers (who can function as reviewers), and keep the blog going at minimum 1 post/2 weeks. Plus, of course, anyone would be welcome to join in to submit ideas, posts, tools, projects, etc, that we may cover, or even submit full fledged articles that could be published as-is. All of this depends on whether there are enough users interested in contributing, in the first place :)